# Parameter count mismatch exception at design time when using itemssource property of raddatagrid

Tags: c#, telerik, uwp, telerik-grid, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP project running in windows 10. In my mainpage.xml I have a RadDataGrid, which i'm binding to a collection on my viewmodel, this works correctly at runtime. However at design time, I get a exception which prevents me from using the designer. If I remove the ItemsSource from the raddatagrid the designer works perfectly, so I guess it's something to do with that, but I'm unsure what.

Many Thanks

XAML snippets:

```
<Page x:Class="UWP.MainPage"    
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"    
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
      xmlns:local="using:UWP"
      xmlns:common="using:DataObjects"    
      xmlns:tgrid="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid"   
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
      mc:Ignorable="d">

<tgrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" 
                   ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Tasks}"
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">                      
</tgrid:RadDataGrid>
```

Model snippet:

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<DataObjects.Task> Tasks { get; }
```

Stack trace:

```
TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at Telerik.Data.Core.BindingExpressionHelper.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CreateGetValueFunc>b__0(Object item)
   at Telerik.Data.Core.Fields.PropertyInfoFieldInfo.GetValue(Object item)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.DataGridTypedColumn.GetValueForInstance(Object instance)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.ITable.GetCellValue(ItemInfo rowItemInfo, ItemInfo columnItemInfo)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.CellsController`1.GetCellDecorator(IItemInfoNode parentRow, ItemInfo columnItemInfo, Int32 rowLine, Int32 columnLine)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.CellsController`1.GenerateCellsForRow(IItemInfoNode rowDecorator, Int32 rowSlot)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.GenerateCellsForReadOnlyRow(Int32 rowSlot, Double largestRowElementWidth, IItemInfoNode rowDecorator)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.ITable.GenerateCellsForRow(Int32 rowSlot, Double largestRowElementHeight, IItemInfoNode rowDecorator)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.GenerateCellsForLine(Int32 slot, Double largestLength, T lastElement)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.GenerateContainer(IList`1 itemInfos)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.MeasureForward(MeasureContext& context)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.MeasureVertically(RadSize availableSize, Double offset, Double bufferScale)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.OnMeasure(RadSize availableSize, Double offset, Int32 frozenElementsCount, Double verticalBufferScale)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.MeasureCells(RadSize newAvailableSize)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.OnCellsPanelMeasure(RadSize newAvailableSize)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Primitives.DataGridCellsPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Primitives.DataGridRootPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.RadControl.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it something, that can break your UI, you can use something like this:

```
private static bool? _isInDesignMode;

/// <summary>
/// Gets a value indicating whether the control is in design mode (running in Blend
/// or Visual Studio).
/// </summary>
public static bool IsInDesignModeStatic
{
    get
    {
        if (!_isInDesignMode.HasValue)
        {
#if SILVERLIGHT
            _isInDesignMode = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool;
#else
            var prop = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;
            _isInDesignMode
                = (bool)DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                .FromProperty(prop, typeof(FrameworkElement))
                .Metadata.DefaultValue;
#endif
        }

        return _isInDesignMode.Value;
    }
}
```

This property will protect your code and it will not executed at design mode.
Also you can use MVVM library like MVVMLight or something else.